# Minimization of $xA + \sqrt[x]{s}B$??

Tags: optimization

Let $x$ be a variable (positive integer), and $A, s, B$ constants.
Then I want to know the way to minimize $xA + \sqrt[x]{s}B$.
How can we solve it? All of $A, B, s$ are positive integers.
The following conditions hold $A > B$ and $ x < s$.

Comment: That depends on what A, B and s can be. Are they real numbers? Are A and B Positive or negative? The power function is monotonically increasing with s no matter what x you choose. I’m no expert but I think there’s a few  details missing...

Comment: @Infinity77 Hello, I added the details. Thanks